# Algorthms or data structure books in scheme

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, scheme

There are very good books on Data Structures and/or algorithms featuring languages like C, C++ or Python. A particular example is "Data Structures Using C and C++ by Yedidyah Langsam, Moshe J. Augenstein and Aaron M. Tenenbaum".

In similar vein, are there books on data structures and/or algorithms in scheme programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), more commonly known as SICP.

Comment: structure and interpretation :)

Answer (score 5):

To add to Chris Jester-Young's answer you have [SICP as videoes lectures](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/) as well, taught by the authors of the book. It's worth the time! The Scheme standard has changed a little since then, but if you use DrRacket you may be interested in a [SICP compatibility module](http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/) which is really easy to install.

[Purely functional data structures](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) (PDF), also available as a book in book stores. It's language agnostic and the code of the book is in ML, but it says it can easily be ported to strict evaluation language, like Scheme.